# Dict com atributos repetidos Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Boa tarde!
Estou montando um formdata para um post,

```
    formdata = {
    'data': '',
    'controle': 'ADMIN',
    'g-recaptcha-response': recaptcha_response
    }
    for numero in nDams:
        formdata['nu_dam[]'] = numero
```

eu preciso que o atributo nu_dam[], se repita quantas vezes for necessário, 
logicamente da maneira acima, no resultado tem somente 1 num_dam[], sempre o ultimo da lista.
Tem alguma maneira para que no final do for o formdata esteja +/- assim

```
        formdata = {
        'data': '',
        'controle': 'ADMIN',
        'g-recaptcha-response': recaptcha_response,
        'nu_dam[]' : '123456',
        'nu_dam[]' : '123457',
        'nu_dam[]' : '123458',
        'nu_dam[]' : '123459'
    }
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: use uma lista como valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente isto:

```
formdata = {
    'data': '',
    'controle': 'ADMIN',
    'g-recaptcha-response': 'recaptcha_response',
    'nu_dam' : [
        '123456',
        '123457',
        '123458',
        '123459'
    ]
}
```

Mas depende a lib de HTTP que você está usando, no básico isto é um array `name="nu_dam[]"` para o payload ou querystring se vindo de um HTML, ou seja é não é que você vai trabalhar assim, isto é somente no HTML.

Para adicionar use append:

```
formdata = {
   'data': '',
   'controle': 'ADMIN',
   'g-recaptcha-response': 'asdasd',
   'nu_dam': []
}


for numero in nDams:
    formdata['nu_dam'].append(numero)
```

Comment: opa alterei `formdata['nu_dam[]'].append(numero)` e funcionou! obrigado